# $x$-values for tangent to the curve then to a perpendicular lines

Tags: calculus

Find any $x$-values for which the tangent to the curve $y=5x-x^2$ is perpendicular to the line $4x-2y-1=0$.

So do I use the $m_1 \times m_2= -1$ to show it's perpendicular or what? I'm really confused--do you find the tangent to the curve of the first equation but then perpendicular to the line? The Answers say x=2 and 3/4 how do i get there

Comment: What is the derivative or slope of $y$ and what must its relation be with the slope of the given line? Then solve for all points on the domain of $y$ for which this relation holds. Possibly draw a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$4x-2y-1=0\Rightarrow 2y=4x-1\Rightarrow y=2x-\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow m_1=2$

So the slope of the perpendicular is $m_2=-\frac{1}{2}$

$ y=5x-x^2$, differentialting we get $\frac{dy}{dx}=5-2x$

$m_2=5-2x$